# How can I count the rows with unique dates within a ForEach Loop?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am currently trying to loop through the following data and count the number of rows that have a unique date. i.e. the answer to the dataset below should be 8.

Data Table[image]

My attempt is below, however the if statement I use only ever returns a true value - not sure why it won't return false when 'date' is equal to 'dateCheck[i -1].  When I print the values to logs, they are different but the if statement still returns true?

```
function rowCount() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow - 1,17).getValues();   
  var dateCheck = []
  var uniqueDates = 0
  data.forEach(function(row,i) {
    var date = row[0];
    dateCheck.push(date);
    if (date != dateCheck[i - 1]) {
    Logger.log('new date');
    uniqueDates += 1  
    }
    else { 
    Logger.log('same day');
    }     
  Logger.log(uniqueDates);  
  });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fetch date values from a Google Spreadsheet, they are supplied as Javascript Date objects. You can't directly compare the values of two objects, as they will never evaluate to equal.

For example, if you create two identical dates, and compare them directly, like so:

```
var date1 = new Date(2020,01,01);
var date2 = new Date(2020,01,01);
if(date1 == date2){
   console.log('dates are equal');
}else{
   console.log('dates are not equal');
}
```

this will output "dates are not equal"

Instead, you need to store a representation of the dates you can compare against. Your best option is to use [Date.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime), which returns a timestamp in milliseconds that represents the date.

```
  data.forEach(function(row,i) {
    var date = row[0];
    dateCheck.push(date.getTime());
    if (date.getTime() != dateCheck[i - 1]) {
       Logger.log('new date');
       uniqueDates += 1  
    }
    else { 
       Logger.log('same day');
    }     
  }
```

You mention in your question you are looking for unique dates, but in your code you are really identifying changes in dates between rows. I assume you have your data sorted by date, in which case your current code will work. However, if you don't want to sort your data, or want to guarantee unique dates, you can use indexOf like so:

```
    if (dateCheck.indexOf(date.getTime()) > -1) {
       Logger.log('new date');
       uniqueDates += 1  
    }
```

This checks for any instance of the current date anywhere in your dateCheck array, regardless of sorting. Note that we check if it's > -1, because you could have a match at index 0 of the array.

Comment: Thank you so much, this now works great - really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function countUniqueDates() {
  const sr=4;
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getRange(sr,1,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,sh.getLastColumn());
  const v=rg.getValues();
  var uA=[];
  v.forEach(function(r,i){
    var ds=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(r[0]),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"E MMM dd, yyyy");
    if(uA.indexOf(ds)==-1) {
      uA.push(ds);
    }              
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(`There are ${uA.length} dates in this sheet.`);
}
```

Here's my data:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
0,1,2,3,4,5
HDR1,HDR2,HDR3,HDR4,HDR5,HDR6
Tue Feb 11 2020 06:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),1,2,3,4,5
Tue Feb 11 2020 06:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),2,3,4,5,6
Tue Feb 11 2020 06:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),3,4,5,6,7
Tue Feb 11 2020 07:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),4,5,6,7,8
Tue Feb 11 2020 07:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),5,6,7,8,9
Tue Feb 11 2020 07:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),6,7,8,9,10
Tue Feb 11 2020 08:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),7,8,9,10,11
Tue Feb 11 2020 08:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),8,9,10,11,12
Tue Feb 11 2020 08:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),9,10,11,12,13
Tue Feb 11 2020 09:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),10,11,12,13,14
Tue Feb 11 2020 09:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),11,12,13,14,15
Tue Feb 11 2020 09:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),12,13,14,15,16
Tue Feb 11 2020 10:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),13,14,15,16,17
Tue Feb 11 2020 10:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),14,15,16,17,18
Tue Feb 11 2020 10:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),15,16,17,18,19
Tue Feb 11 2020 11:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),16,17,18,19,20
Tue Feb 11 2020 11:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),17,18,19,20,21
Tue Feb 11 2020 11:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),18,19,20,21,22
Tue Feb 11 2020 12:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),19,20,21,22,23
Tue Feb 11 2020 12:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),20,21,22,23,24
Tue Feb 11 2020 12:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),21,22,23,24,25
Tue Feb 11 2020 13:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),22,23,24,25,26
Tue Feb 11 2020 13:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),23,24,25,26,27
Tue Feb 11 2020 13:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),24,25,26,27,28
Tue Feb 11 2020 14:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),25,26,27,28,29
Tue Feb 11 2020 14:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),26,27,28,29,30
Tue Feb 11 2020 14:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),27,28,29,30,31
Tue Feb 11 2020 15:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),28,29,30,31,32
Tue Feb 11 2020 15:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),29,30,31,32,33
Tue Feb 11 2020 15:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),30,31,32,33,34
Tue Feb 11 2020 16:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),31,32,33,34,35
Tue Feb 11 2020 16:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),32,33,34,35,36
Tue Feb 11 2020 16:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),33,34,35,36,37
Tue Feb 11 2020 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),34,35,36,37,38
Tue Feb 11 2020 17:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),35,36,37,38,39
Tue Feb 11 2020 17:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),36,37,38,39,40
Tue Feb 11 2020 18:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),37,38,39,40,41
Tue Feb 11 2020 18:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),38,39,40,41,42
Tue Feb 11 2020 18:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),39,40,41,42,43
Tue Feb 11 2020 19:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),40,41,42,43,44
Tue Feb 11 2020 19:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),41,42,43,44,45
Tue Feb 11 2020 19:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),42,43,44,45,46
Tue Feb 11 2020 20:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),43,44,45,46,47
Tue Feb 11 2020 20:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),44,45,46,47,48
Tue Feb 11 2020 20:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),45,46,47,48,49
Tue Feb 11 2020 21:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),46,47,48,49,50
Tue Feb 11 2020 21:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),47,48,49,50,51
Tue Feb 11 2020 21:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),48,49,50,51,52
Tue Feb 11 2020 22:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),49,50,51,52,53
Tue Feb 11 2020 22:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),50,51,52,53,54
Tue Feb 11 2020 22:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),51,52,53,54,55
Tue Feb 11 2020 23:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),52,53,54,55,56
Tue Feb 11 2020 23:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),53,54,55,56,57
Tue Feb 11 2020 23:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),54,55,56,57,58
Wed Feb 12 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),55,56,57,58,59
Wed Feb 12 2020 00:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),56,57,58,59,60
Wed Feb 12 2020 00:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),57,58,59,60,61
Wed Feb 12 2020 01:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),58,59,60,61,62
Wed Feb 12 2020 01:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),59,60,61,62,63
Wed Feb 12 2020 01:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),60,61,62,63,64
Wed Feb 12 2020 02:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),61,62,63,64,65
Wed Feb 12 2020 02:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),62,63,64,65,66
Wed Feb 12 2020 02:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),63,64,65,66,67
Wed Feb 12 2020 03:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),64,65,66,67,68
Wed Feb 12 2020 03:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),65,66,67,68,69
Wed Feb 12 2020 03:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),66,67,68,69,70
Wed Feb 12 2020 04:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),67,68,69,70,71
Wed Feb 12 2020 04:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),68,69,70,71,72
Wed Feb 12 2020 04:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),69,70,71,72,73
Wed Feb 12 2020 05:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),70,71,72,73,74
Wed Feb 12 2020 05:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),71,72,73,74,75
Wed Feb 12 2020 05:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),72,73,74,75,76
Wed Feb 12 2020 06:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),73,74,75,76,77
Wed Feb 12 2020 06:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),74,75,76,77,78
Wed Feb 12 2020 06:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),75,76,77,78,79
Wed Feb 12 2020 07:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),76,77,78,79,80
Wed Feb 12 2020 07:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),77,78,79,80,81
Wed Feb 12 2020 07:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),78,79,80,81,82
Wed Feb 12 2020 08:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),79,80,81,82,83
Wed Feb 12 2020 08:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),80,81,82,83,84
Wed Feb 12 2020 08:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),81,82,83,84,85
Wed Feb 12 2020 09:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),82,83,84,85,86
Wed Feb 12 2020 09:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),83,84,85,86,87
Wed Feb 12 2020 09:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),84,85,86,87,88
Wed Feb 12 2020 10:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),85,86,87,88,89
Wed Feb 12 2020 10:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),86,87,88,89,90
Wed Feb 12 2020 10:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),87,88,89,90,91
Wed Feb 12 2020 11:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),88,89,90,91,92
Wed Feb 12 2020 11:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),89,90,91,92,93
Wed Feb 12 2020 11:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),90,91,92,93,94
Wed Feb 12 2020 12:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),91,92,93,94,95
Wed Feb 12 2020 12:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),92,93,94,95,96
Wed Feb 12 2020 12:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),93,94,95,96,97
Wed Feb 12 2020 13:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),94,95,96,97,98
Wed Feb 12 2020 13:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),95,96,97,98,99
Wed Feb 12 2020 13:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),96,97,98,99,100
Wed Feb 12 2020 14:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),97,98,99,100,101
Wed Feb 12 2020 14:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),98,99,100,101,102
Wed Feb 12 2020 14:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),99,100,101,102,103
Wed Feb 12 2020 15:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),100,101,102,103,104
Wed Feb 12 2020 15:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),101,102,103,104,105
Wed Feb 12 2020 15:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),102,103,104,105,106
Wed Feb 12 2020 16:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),103,104,105,106,107
Wed Feb 12 2020 16:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),104,105,106,107,108
Wed Feb 12 2020 16:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),105,106,107,108,109
Wed Feb 12 2020 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),106,107,108,109,110
Wed Feb 12 2020 17:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),107,108,109,110,111
Wed Feb 12 2020 17:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),108,109,110,111,112
Wed Feb 12 2020 18:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),109,110,111,112,113
Wed Feb 12 2020 18:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),110,111,112,113,114
Wed Feb 12 2020 18:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),111,112,113,114,115
Wed Feb 12 2020 19:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),112,113,114,115,116
Wed Feb 12 2020 19:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),113,114,115,116,117
Wed Feb 12 2020 19:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),114,115,116,117,118
Wed Feb 12 2020 20:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),115,116,117,118,119
Wed Feb 12 2020 20:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),116,117,118,119,120
Wed Feb 12 2020 20:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),117,118,119,120,121
Wed Feb 12 2020 21:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),118,119,120,121,122
Wed Feb 12 2020 21:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),119,120,121,122,123
Wed Feb 12 2020 21:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),120,121,122,123,124
Wed Feb 12 2020 22:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),121,122,123,124,125
Wed Feb 12 2020 22:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),122,123,124,125,126
Wed Feb 12 2020 22:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),123,124,125,126,127
Wed Feb 12 2020 23:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),124,125,126,127,128
Wed Feb 12 2020 23:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),125,126,127,128,129
Wed Feb 12 2020 23:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),126,127,128,129,130
Thu Feb 13 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),127,128,129,130,131
Thu Feb 13 2020 00:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),128,129,130,131,132
Thu Feb 13 2020 00:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),129,130,131,132,133
Thu Feb 13 2020 01:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),130,131,132,133,134
Thu Feb 13 2020 01:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),131,132,133,134,135
Thu Feb 13 2020 01:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),132,133,134,135,136
Thu Feb 13 2020 02:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),133,134,135,136,137
Thu Feb 13 2020 02:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),134,135,136,137,138
Thu Feb 13 2020 02:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),135,136,137,138,139
Thu Feb 13 2020 03:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),136,137,138,139,140
Thu Feb 13 2020 03:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),137,138,139,140,141
Thu Feb 13 2020 03:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),138,139,140,141,142
Thu Feb 13 2020 04:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),139,140,141,142,143
Thu Feb 13 2020 04:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),140,141,142,143,144
Thu Feb 13 2020 04:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),141,142,143,144,145
Thu Feb 13 2020 05:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),142,143,144,145,146
Thu Feb 13 2020 05:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),143,144,145,146,147
Thu Feb 13 2020 05:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),144,145,146,147,148
Thu Feb 13 2020 06:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),145,146,147,148,149
Thu Feb 13 2020 06:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),146,147,148,149,150
Thu Feb 13 2020 06:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),147,148,149,150,151
Thu Feb 13 2020 07:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),148,149,150,151,152
Thu Feb 13 2020 07:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),149,150,151,152,153
Thu Feb 13 2020 07:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),150,151,152,153,154
Thu Feb 13 2020 08:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),151,152,153,154,155
Thu Feb 13 2020 08:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),152,153,154,155,156
Thu Feb 13 2020 08:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),153,154,155,156,157
Thu Feb 13 2020 09:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),154,155,156,157,158
Thu Feb 13 2020 09:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),155,156,157,158,159
Thu Feb 13 2020 09:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),156,157,158,159,160
Thu Feb 13 2020 10:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),157,158,159,160,161
Thu Feb 13 2020 10:20:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),158,159,160,161,162
Thu Feb 13 2020 10:40:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),159,160,161,162,163
Thu Feb 13 2020 11:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),160,161,162,163,164
```